# Not able to execute sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

```
select tt.threshold_id
from   (select sum(amount) over (partition by tt.threshold_type 
                                     order by tt.threshold_type ) amt
        from   cash_transactions) cash,
       thresholds tt
where  tt.threshold_amount < cash.amt
```

the rdms involved is oracle the error is

```
" ORA-00904: "TT"."THRESHOLD_TYPE": invalid identifier"
```

what i want to do with this query is :

1. threshold table contains a column threshold type which contain column name of the cash transactions table
2. And for each record from the threshold table we need to compare the sum(amount) group by the threshold type  from cash transactions table .
3. and the amount fetched is compared with the threshold_amount of the the threshold table
4. and i need to select the threshold_id

Thresholds Table:

```
Threshold_id        Threshold_type          Threshold_amount
============================================================
threshold_1         p_id                    450
threshold_2         p_id,to_acc_main_num    100
```

Cash Transactions Table:

```
Tran_inst_id    p_id    amount    to_acc_main_num
=================================================
1               E1      100       123
2               E2      200       5765  
3               E1      200       687
4               E2      300       890
5               E1      100       462
```

DESIRED OUTPUT :

Lets take the first fetch :the first record from the threshold table

```
Threshold_id        Threshold_type          Threshold_amount
============================================================
threshold_1         p_id                    100000
```

1.now the threshold_type is p_id ok
2.So i need to group by pid from cash_transactions table.
3.so the desired result from this is (but i have to take sum on basis of p_id only)
not tran_inst_id in this case

```
Tran_inst_id  p_id    sum(amount)
======================================
1             E1        400
2             E2        500
3             E1        400
4             E2        500
5             E1        400
```

1.now each records amount above  is compared with the amount of threshold_1 record.
2.so 450 threshold_amount for threshold_1 is compared with all the above record
3.so the required output will be

```
theshold_id   Tran_inst_id
==================================
thresold_1      2
threshold_1     4 
- the above result is for first record of threshold table ,now the same continues for the second record.
```

EDIT:Suppose if the threshold_type is null ,then we not need to include partition by part in the query ,then how it can be obtain?

Comment: it would be easier to read if you put it in code and formatted the lines so you can see what is missing.  My guess is you are missing a from statement for your inner select, but I don't have Oracle, so I can't test it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run this query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963348/how-to-run-this-query)

Comment: @marc_s :yes ,i have not mentioned the details...sorry for that

Comment: @Paul W :i am not getting your point

Comment: Please provide the output of `desc thresholds` and `desc cash_transactions` and a few sample rows of both tables that belong together. With the current info, it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Daniel :wait i ll provide the data

Comment: @Daniel:Thresholds Table

Threshold_id Threshold_type   Threshold_amount
threshold_1  p_id      10000
threshold_2  p_id,to_acc_main_num  1000

Comment: Please update your original question with this data!

Comment: @Daniel - the data is now available

Comment: @gaurav: Thanks for the update. I still don't understand how it should work. How to interpret the column `Thresholds.Threshold_type`?

Comment: Maybe provide an example of what you want your subquery to return with the provided sample data.

Comment: @Daniel- do u understand what is my requirement?

Comment: @Daniel-will provide the data wait

Comment: @james:I need some input ,do u get my query?Is there any other way to do?

Comment: @Daniel:suppose i fetch 10 rows from the innner query on the basis of the threshold_type :eg-Select sum(amount) over (partition by participant_id order by participant_id)amt from cash_transactions ......now the threshold_amount from threshold table is compared with amt of the 10 rows from the inner query .

Comment: You will get several rows as a result of the subquery. One row per distinct p_id, i.e. with the above sample data, you will get one row with 1272 (for E1) and one with 6655 (for E2). Now what? Return the threshold_id if any of those rows is above the threshold? Or if all are above it?

Comment: @Daniel:Now compare this two records from the inner query with the first record of the threshold table (comparing the threshold_amount 100000 with 1272 and 6655)...ok

Comment: @all-  please see the requirement is been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only possible with dynamic sql, since the number of columns in the group by clause is variable. 
For example with a function:

```
    create or replace
    function sum_cash_transactions ( p_threshold_type varchar2) return number
    is
      v_result NUMBER;
    begin
      execute immediate ' select max( sum_amount) 
                          from( select sum(amount) as sum_amount
                                from   cash_transactions
                                group by ' || p_threshold_type || ' )'
     into v_result;
     return v_result;
     end;
/
```

and then

```
select threshold_id
 from thresholds
 where threshold_amount < sum_cash_transactions(threshold_type);
```

EDIT due to new requirements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package pkg AS
  TYPE res_rec_type IS RECORD (
    threshold_id  VARCHAR2(200)
  , Tran_inst_id  NUMBER(10,0)
  , sum_amount    NUMBER(22)
  );
  TYPE res_tab_type IS TABLE of res_rec_type;
  FUNCTION f1 RETURN  res_tab_type PIPELINED;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg AS

  FUNCTION f1 RETURN  res_tab_type PIPELINED
  IS
    CUR    SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_rec  res_rec_type;
  BEGIN
    FOR treshold in ( SELECT Threshold_id,  Threshold_type,   Threshold_amount FROM thresholds)
    LOOP
      OPEN CUR FOR 'SELECT ' || threshold.Threshold_id || ', tTran_inst_id,  s FROM (SELECT  tTran_inst_id, SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY ' || p_Threshold_type || ') as s from cash_transactions ) WHERE s > ' || treshold.Threshold_amount ;
      LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO v_rec;
        EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
        pipe row(v_rec);
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
    RETURN;
  END;
END;
/

SELECT * form table(pkg.f1);
```

Comment: The question is unclear about the output desired, but I suspect he doesn't just want the IDs of the thresholds that are exceeded by some set of transactions -- he probably wants each set of transactions that exceeds a threshold.  But your answer gives me an interesting idea -- if that function were converted to a pipeline that can return multiple rows, then it could be called from a simple query as you suggest and return all the information that I think would be desired.

Comment: @dave costa the OP has clearly written: **"select id threshold"** :), but yes you are right, one is much more flexible with a pipline function.

Comment: @schurik- lets take the 1st fetch   ....suppose the inner query returns 10 result ,so the inner query has ten sum_amount ,which is to be compared with the 1st record of the threshold table,and the corresponding threshold_id is to be fetched

Comment: @schurik- above solution will not give the required answer

Comment: @gaurav the inner query return the maximum of Sums pro group from threshold_type. For you testdata the function will return 500 for threshold_1 and 300 for threshold_2. Than you compare this values with  threshold_amount in the query. "threshold_2" will be return from the query, while 100 < 300. "threshold_1" will be not return from the query while 1000 > 500.  What is the require answer?

Comment: @schurik:You function will return only 1 record from the innner query ,but i want multiple records ...suppose i need to do group by participant_id then ,it will return record on basis of participant_id ,and for each participant_id ,we need to compare record from threshold_amount in threshold_table

Comment: @all-correction:-I want to fetch the Tran_inst_id and the threshold_id

Comment: @gaurav: Could you please add to your question the the desired result for your provided test data. To make clear what exactly do you expect. _________________          When you group by p_id then you have two records:  with p_id = E1 and  p_id = E2. In what form do you want to see the Tran_inst_id here?

Comment: @schurik:i have put explanation in the Question above please go through that...thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate issue is that `tt` is not in the scope of the subquery on `cash_transactions`, so you can't reference `threshold_type` in that subquery.  The syntactical fix for this would be to convert to a join, with a normal group by.

However, this still won't accomplish what you want, because it will group by the values contained in `threshold_type` -- it won't be interpreted as a list of columns to actually group by.  The query parser has to know the columns being referenced at parse time, and what you are trying to do is determine them at execution time.

The standard way to deal with this is dynamic SQL, where you construct the query as a string in procedural code, then explicitly parse and execute it.  A simple implementation in PL/SQL would look like:

```
FOR tt in (SELECT * from thresholds) LOOP
  OPEN a_refcursor FOR 'SELECT SUM(amount) FROM cash_transactions GROUP BY '
                       ||tt.threshold_type||
                       ' HAVING SUM(amount) > '||TO_CHAR(tt.threshold_amount);
  LOOP
    FETCH a_refcursor INTO local_var;
    EXIT WHEN a_refcursor%NOTFOUND;
    -- do whatever it is you want to do with the information here
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

However, I'm guessing that you would like to know the values of the dynamic columns for which the threshold has been exceeded.  That can easily be added to the query:

```
  OPEN a_refcursor FOR 'SELECT '|| tt.threshold_type ||
                       ',SUM(amount) FROM cash_transactions GROUP BY '
                       ||tt.threshold_type||
                       ' HAVING SUM(amount) > '||TO_CHAR(tt.threshold_amount);
```

But the difficulty is that the number of columns returned by the dynamic query is now variable, so the FETCH statement will not work.  In this case you would have to use calls to DBMS_SQL to handle the dynamic SQL, which allows you to fetch column values by position.